# Errors When Upon Watchkit Extension

Tags: ios, uikit, mapkit, watchkit, cllocationmanager

My first attempt at building a watchOS app is starting a little rough.

After I select the watchkit extension in the target membership box within the file inspector several errors pop up immediately regarding my CLLocationManager Delegate Class and I am unaware of why this would be the case and not sure how to track down answers for these problems.

Because it is for a watch is there special limitations to what is allowed to be integrated in the shareable code from iOS and watchOS?

Unsure why especially activity type would be unavailable.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import UIKit

class TrackLocationManagerDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
      lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
             var locationManager            = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate        = LocationManagerDelegate.sharedInstance
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        // ERROR - activityType unavailable
        locationManager.activityType    = CLActivityType.fitness 

        locationManager.distanceFilter  = 10.0

        return locationManager
      }()

     // ERROR - Use of undeclared type MKPolyline
    fileprivate lazy var polyline = MKPolyline() 

    // ERROR -  Use of Undeclared type UIViewController
    func startUpdatingLocationIfAuthorized( inViewController vc: UIViewController) {  
        guard CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            TrackLocationManagerDelegate.sharedInstance.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            return
        }

        TrackLocationManagerDelegate.sharedInstance.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, carefully read documentation for [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation) and [MapKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit) frameworks. Not all symbols are available on watchOS. For example, `MKPolyline` is available on iOS 4.0+, macOS 10.9+, tvOS 9.2+ but not on watchOS.

You also can't use `UIViewController` and the entire `UIKit` on Apple Watch. Use `WatchKit` UI classes, such as `WKInterfaceController`.

Good luck in further learning!

Comment: Thank you, Went through the documentation it answered all my questions!